# div dropdown not showing

Tags: html, css, django

I am attempting to create a dropdown for a user. The problem is that it doesn't show up at all.

```
<div class="account-wrap">
        <div class="inside-account trade-sell-div">
            <a class = "trade-sell-button" href="{% url 'product' %}">Trade/Sell</a>
        </div>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <div class = "inside-account chat-box-dropdown">
                <a class="imgs-signed-in"><img style="height:45px !important;" src = "{% static "imgs/chat-box.png" %}" alt="Chat Box"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="inside-account user-dropdown">
                <a class="imgs-signed-in user-icon-dropdown"><img src="{% static "imgs/user-icon.png" %}" alt="User"></a>
                <div class="dropdown-frame">
                    <div id="triangle"></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="inside-account">
                <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

css

```
.dropdown-frame{
    position: absolute;
    height: 40rem;
    width: 10rem;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}
#triangle  {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    content: '';
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid white;
}
.dropdown-wrapper {
    right: 0;
    height: 40rem;
    width: 10rem;
    top: 56px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    z-index: 122;
}
```

Basically the triangle shows up on the nav bar but the part under the triangle does not show up at all. When I move the div elements outside the nav, it actually shows up. Does anyone have any explanation as to why my div dropdown-wrapper does not show up?

Comment: nevermind I figure out the problem. The problem was that i had overflow hidden on my nav.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you missed the **.** before **dropdown-frame** class

Comment: oh no sorry that was just a mistake when I pasted the code in my code has the . in it

Answer (score 0):

It should be `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}` instead of `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`

Comment: thats not the problem either. My problem is in the css and the html